# Java -install vs PATH

Tags: java, ubuntu, path

I am new to Ubuntu and trying to install a particular version of java.

I downloaded the `jdk1.7.0_51` binaries in my Ubuntu machine and exported the variable `JAVA_HOME='home/programs/jdk1.7.0_51` and the `PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`. However when I type `java -version` in the command line I get:

```
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

The displayed java version (`1.6.0_27`) is different than the version declared in the `PATH`. There was an older version which I removed through the software center but the issue remains. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're not using the oracle-java7-installer?  Or even installing OpenJDK7 directly from apt-get?

Comment: @Makoto I was following the directions of the "Apache Mahout Cookbook" that instructed the direct download of the binaries.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you already have `openjdk` installed (by default probably) on your system and the binaries provided by openjdk are already registered in `$PATH`. And that's where your problem is. Downloading the oracle jdk binaries and installing them in a custom location and exporting that location in `JAVA_HOME`, is not enough. You also need to add the path to the jdk binaries (`javac`, `java`, `jar`, etc) to the PATH environment variable.

A better way to do this is to install the oracle jdk via pre-packaged versions provided by ubuntu community: [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html). This would configure the path for you and set the necessary environment variables. And use alternatives to configure which would be the default jdk to use:

`update-alternatives --config java`

Or simply remove openjdk if you don't need it.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I did use your link and the variables are set correctly.